# Aeson: parse nested object as (Map String MyShinyType)

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have json-schema file with "properties" field.

```
{
...
   "properties": {
       "id": {
           "description": "ID",
           "type": "integer",
           "required": true
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see properties isn't an array, but object. I want to parse this structure with aeson as `Map String Schema`

My code at moment looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module GimmeModels.Schema.JSONSchema.Types
where

import Data.Aeson
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>), empty)
import Data.Attoparsec (parse, Result(..), IResult( Done ))
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Monad (mzero)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BSL
import qualified Data.Aeson.Types as T
import Data.Map (Map(..))

data Schema = Schema {
      schema      :: Maybe Text
    , id          :: Maybe Text 
    , _type       :: Maybe Type
    , description :: Maybe Text
    , extends     :: Maybe (Map String String)
    , items       :: Maybe Schema 
    , properties  :: Maybe (Map String Schema)
    , required    :: Maybe Bool 
    } deriving (Show)

type SchemaUrl = Text
type Type = Text

type PropsMap = Map String Schema

instance FromJSON Schema where 
     parseJSON (Object v) = 
        Schema <$> v .:? "$schema"
               <*> v .:? "id"
               <*> v .:? "type"
               <*> v .:? "description"
               <*> v .:? "extends"
               <*> v .:? "items"
               <*> v .:? "properties"
               <*> v .:? "required"
     parseJSON _ = empty

parseSchemaFromString :: String -> Maybe Schema
parseSchemaFromString s = 
    case parse json bs of
        (Done rest r) -> T.parseMaybe parseJSON r :: Maybe Schema 
        _ -> error "FAIL" 
    where bs = BS.pack s
```

And it doesn't work.
If I turn on Generics and auto-derive FromJSON interface, Aeson will parse properties like a charm, but I really need to map "$schema" and "type" fields by hand.

What should I do to parse it properly?

Guys, after 8 hours of sleep I finally realized what problem is! In my schema there is field `"type": ["string", "null"]`, but parser assumes "type" is String. Thank you all for help :)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what doesn't work (Input, produced Output and Expected Output?). Or is it a compiler error?

Comment: No, `parseSchemaFromString` just returns Nothing.

Comment: Does `decode` not work? Something like `decode "..." :: Maybe (Map String Schema)` is usually sufficient using the `instance FromJSON v => FromJSON (Map String v)`.

Comment: Guys, after 8 hours of sleep I finally realized what problem is! In my schema there is field "type": ["string", "null"], but parser assumes "type" as String. Thank you all for help :)